# Regex for matching different float formats

Tags: java, regex, scala

I'm looking for a regex in scala to match several floats:

```
    9,487,346 -> should match
    9.487.356,453->should match
    38,4 -> match
    -38,4 -> should match
    -38.5
    -9,487,346.76
    -38 -> should match
```

So basically it should match a number that:

1. possibly gave thousand separators (either comma or dot)
2. possibly are decimal again with either comma or dot as separator

Currently I'm stuck with

```
    val pattern="\\d+((\\.\\d{3}+)?(,\\d{1,2}+)?|(,\\d{3}+)?(\\.\\d{1,2}+)?)"
```

**Edit**: I'm mostly concered with European Notation.

Example where the current pattern not matches: 1,052,161

I guess it would be close enough to match that the String only contains numbers,sign, comma and dot

Comment: What's wrong with your current pattern? What values should it _not_ match?

Comment: use this `"^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$"`

Comment: I think you're asking too much from regex. In particular: zero or more **properly spaced** thousands separators (**might be comma, might be dot**), and zero or one fraction separator (**not same as the thousands separator**). Putting all those rules in a single RE isn't going to be easy.

Comment: Thousand-separator is a misnomer, because some countries use the separator every 2 digits. For example India uses a [different system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system#Use_of_separators). Also, some countries use space as the separator.

Comment: Are you intentionally ignoring [e-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation), like `6.02e23`?

Comment: E notation is not relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as your **edit** suggests, you are willing to accept a string that simply "contains numbers, sign, comma and dot" then the task is trivial.

```
[+-]?\d[\d.,]*
```

**update**

After thinking it over, and considering some options, I realize that your original request is possible if you'll allow for 2 different RE patterns, one for US-style numbers (commas before dot) and one for Euro-style numbers (dots before comma).

```
def isValidNum(num: String): Boolean =
  num.matches("[+-]?\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*(\\.\\d+)?") ||
    num.matches("[+-]?\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{3})*(,\\d+)?")
```

Note that the thousand separators are not optional, so a number like `"1234"` is not evaluated as valid. That can be changed by adding more RE patterns: `|| num.matches("[+-]?\\d+")`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your rules,

> It should match a number that:
>
> - possibly gave thousand separators (either comma or dot)
> - possibly are decimal again with either comma or dot as separator

Regex:

```
^[+-]?\d{1,3}(?:[,.]\d{3})*(?:[,.]\d+)?$
```

- `[+-]?` Allows `+` or `-` or nothing at the start
- `\d{1,3}` allows one to 3 digits
- `([,.]\d{3})` allows `.` or `,` as thousands separator followed by 3 digits (`*` allows unlimited such matches)
- `(?:[,.]\d+)?` allows `.` or `,` as decimal separator followed by at least one digit.

This matches all of the OP's example cases. Take a look at the demo below for more:

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/clUWU1/2/)

However one limitation is it allows `.` or `,` as thousand separator and as decimal separator and doesn't validate that if `,` is thousands separator then `.` *should be* decimal separator. As a result the below cases incorrectly show up as matches:

```
201,350,780,88
211.950.266.4
```

To fix this as well, the previous regex can have 2 alternatives - one to check for a notation that has `,` as thousands separator and `.` as decimal, and another one to check vice-versa. Regex:

```
^[+-]?\d{1,3}(?:(?:(?:\.\d{3})*(?:\,\d+)?)|(?:(?:\,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?))$
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/clUWU1/3/)

Hope this helps!